# Adding second "while (bool exp) give strange result

Tags: c, loops, cs50

I have task to limit outputs opportunity between 1 and 8. If player press less then 1 or more 8 program must return him to the choice option.

After adding second `while` loop and compiling without any mistakes the programm give oportunity input any values and work approprietly with values between 1 and 8 and when we try input less then 1. But something going very strange in case when user inputs more than 8.

Who can explain why?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        n = get_int("Height:");
    }
    while (n < 1);
    while (n > 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please do not post code and other text output as images or links to images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Please paste it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: `while (n>8);` is a loop with no body, That is, all it does is continually check the condition until it becomes false. Since nothing changes `n` in that loop it obviously results in an infinete loop if the condition starts off true. Instead you want `do { ...} while (n<1 || n>8);`

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
do { n = ...; } while (n < 1);

while (n > 8);
```

This is the same as

```
do { n = ...; } while (n < 1);

while (n > 8) { }
```

If `n >= 1` is true, the first loop is exited.

If `n > 8` is also true, the second loop is entered. Since nothing changes `n` in the second loop, the condition never becomes false, so it keep looping indefinitely.

You were looking for

```
do { n = ...; } while (n < 1 || n > 8);
```